# Find coordinates from the length of two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

A corner of the base of a building is 200 feet away from the surveyor, in a
direction 40 degrees north of east, and the building is 150 feet high. What are the coordinates of the point at the top of the building directly above the corner?

---

So 200 and 150 are two separate lengths of the triangle sides and we have a 40 degree angle given to work with.

I am having trouble understand how to find the coordinates of a point in the 3d plane described above and how to use the information given in the problem. Here is my crappy geometric intuition-drawing about it, but I think it is flawed.

Also by "coordinates", it wants a 3d vector $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ right or am I understanding that wrong?

Edit:

So we are given $x_3 = 150$. 
[image]

from pythag, we get $c = 250$. I guess we would also know that the top of the building, $x_1 = 200$. We also know the other angles are both $90^{\circ}$ and $180-90-40=50^{\circ}$. What trigonometry would I use to find $x_2$?

edit: updated drawing

[image]

Comment: $x_3 = 150$. Other components can be found by simple trigonometry.

Comment: @Mick I don't think that is what the question is asking for

Comment: Wasn't "I am having trouble understand how to find the coordinates of a point in the 3d plane described above"  the question you are asking?

Comment: @Mick please see my edits

Comment: The question, asking for coordinates, doesn't make sense unless you have a "coordinate system".  Are you assuming a coordinate system with origin at the corner, x and y axes along the sides of the building and z axis vertical, up the height of the building?

Comment: I am assuming origin is the "surveyor" with the x,y,z axes that you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the figure should be drawn. Those lines in red are on the ground.

[image]

Comment: yup this is pretty much what I ended up doing. Ill edit my main post to show my drawing